# SQL loader installation

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracleclient

How can I install the SQL Loader, when I have installed the Oracle Data Access Components(ODAC) for windows?
I am using oracle DB 11gR2 and oracle ODAC version: 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

Install the Oracle Instant Client 'tools' packages which now [includes SQL*Loader](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump).  Instant Client is a small, free download and much easier to install then a full DB.  You should be able to use a recent (ie. the latest) version of SQL*Loader to connect to your Oracle 11g DB, since most Oracle tools allow cross-version interoperability (Data Pump is an exception).  There are installation instructions on the [Instant Client download page(s)](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).

You will need  the Basic (or Basic Light) package as well as the matching Tools package.  Unzip both.  This is totally separate to your ODAC installation.  Just set PATH to the directory you unzip into.  If globally changing PATH interferes with ODAC, then just set PATH in your command window each time before you run SQL*Loader.  This can also be done in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Use following link to download all installations required for Windows version wise.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

(There is a reason to specify this installation. It gives you all sort of software,instant client or utilities associated with oracle. File size is big almost 1.2 GB in my case.)

Select appropriate version of your windows installation. You should have an account to download this if you don't have please create one while you select the suitable download.

1. Unzip and click on **setup.exe**
2. Select Type of installation as **custom**
3. **"Use Windows built-in Account"** Account option for Oracle Home user Selection Step.
4. Select Installation Location as per your requirement.
5. From **Component Name** please select **Oracle Database Utilities**
6. Complete the installation
7. Open command prompt and type SQLLDR it should give you detailed information about its version and acceptable parameters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install the oracle client software. (Express edition does not include sqlldr.exe)